# Javascript Memory Leaks with Object Property Functions

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a question about Javascript memory leaks which I believe we're seeing in an application and I've been tasked to fix. I'm a relatively new JS developer, so I'm trying to wrap my head around how the GC works and I'm not 100% sure about it yet.

Our application is structured so that there is a big object which has lots of functions as properties. Lots of functions are calling each like the below (extremely simplified) example:

```
var usefulFunctions = {};

usefulFunctions.exampleOne = function(arg1) {
    return usefulFunctions.exampleTwo(arg1);
}

usefulFunctions.exampleTwo = function(arg1) {
    var result = arg1 + 1;
    return result;
}
```

I'm using the Chrome memory profiling tools and seeing functions that are using lots of memory and these functions typically call other functions in the manner above more frequently than other functions which are not using as much memory.

The question is, would you see any benefits or prevent any leaks by restructing the code above to something like:

```
var usefulFunctions = {};

usefulFunctions.exampleOne = function(arg1) {
    return exampleTwo(arg1);
}

function exampleTwo(arg1) {
    var result = arg1 + 1;
    return result;
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding how potential memory leaks can occur and the first example is fine?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I didn't get where you are seeing leaks, sorry. The fact that a piece of code requires a specific amount of memory to execute correctly does not mean that it will leak that memory.